# How to make autoarchive in outlook 2016 for more mailers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving

So basically i have multiple e-mail addresses, I want to make an archive for each of them on a different path, is possible to make it or they need to be on one folder on auto-archive?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the AutoArchive settings can be either per-profile or per-folder. You can't setup AutoArchive folder per-account. So, either use one archive folder for all accounts in a profile or set individual AutoArchive settings for each folder in each account.

The latter can be extremely time-consuming. If you really need a separate AutoArchive folders, I can recommend the free [Set Folder AutoArchive Settings](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderAutoArchive) utility (I'm one of the developers). It can be used to set AutoArchive settings for all folders in the selected account at once.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new .pst file.
When setting AutoArchive, click Browse to locate your new .pst file.
[image]

Regarding how to create a new pst file, please refer to this article:https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-an-outlook-data-file-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c